# Why does my WebGL shader not let me using varyings?

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

When I try to link my vertex and fragment shaders into a program, WebGL throws `Varyings with the same name but different type, or statically used varyings in fragment shader are not declared in vertex shader: textureCoordinates`

I have `varying vec2 test` in both my vertex and fragment shaders, and can't see any reason why the compiler wouldn't be able to find the same `varying` in both.

Vertex Shader:

```
varying vec2 test;
void main(void) {
   gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   test = vec2(1.0, 0.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision highp float;
varying vec2 test;
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(test.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Test code:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
gl = canvas.getContext('webgl')
let vert = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vert, "varying vec2 test;\nvoid main(void) {\n   gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);\n   test = vec2(1.0, 0.0);\n}");
gl.compileShader(vert);

let frag = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(frag, "precision highp float;\nvarying vec2 test;\nvoid main() {\n\tgl_FragColor = vec4(test.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n}");
gl.compileShader(frag);

let program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vert);
gl.attachShader(program, frag);

gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm not getting any errors with Chrome for Windows v51.0.2704.103m (64-bit). Here is the [exact code](http://pastebin.com/6EXAetZ2) I am executing.

Comment: @Exide updating my browser fixed the problem. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by updating Chrome for OSX from v51.something to  52.0.2743.82 (64-bit) Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I wonder if it's because you're not using the textureCoordinates in your fragment shader. The names & types match just fine, so i don't think that's the issue. I've done the same thing here:

Frag:

```
// The fragment shader is the rasterization process of webgl

// use float precision for this shader
precision mediump float;

// the input texture coordinate values from the vertex shader
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
// the texture data, this is bound via gl.bindTexture()
uniform sampler2D texture;
// the colour uniform
uniform vec3 color;

void main(void) {
  // gl_FragColor is the output colour for a particular pixel.
  // use the texture data, specifying the texture coordinate, and modify it by the colour value.
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t)) * vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Vert:

```
// setup passable attributes for the vertex position & texture coordinates
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

// setup a uniform for our perspective * lookat * model view matrix
uniform mat4 uMatrix;
// setup an output variable for our texture coordinates
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main() {
  // take our final matrix to modify the vertex position to display the data on screen in a perspective way
  // With shader code here, you can modify the look of an image in all sorts of ways
  // the 4th value here is the w coordinate, and it is called Homogeneous coordinates, (x,y,z,w).
  // It effectively allows the perspective math to work. With 3d graphics, it should be set to 1. Less than 1 will appear too big
  // Greater than 1 will appear too small
  gl_Position = uMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
```

Comment: I've modified my original question to contain a minimum working example of the code failing. It appears to fail even if I do make use of the varying.